# cx freeze with wxpython, adding images with exe

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets, py2exe, cx-freeze

I am trying to use a bitmap with wxpython

in main.py i have:

```
imag=wx.Image("picture.bmp",wx.BITMAP_TYPE_BMP).ConvertToBitmap()
```

picture.bmp is in the same folder as main.py,
this program works when running in the IDE

it does not work when I make an exe.

When i run the exe created by cx_freeze I get a cmd box that pops up and shows this:

```
 wxBitmap CreatefromImage(): invalid image
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this methods

```
import imp
import os
import sys

def main_is_frozen():
    return (hasattr(sys, "frozen") or # new py2exe
            hasattr(sys, "importers") # old py2exe
            or imp.is_frozen("__main__")) # tools/freeze

def get_main_dir():
   if main_is_frozen():
       return os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
   return os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])
```

And get image path using this code

```
imag=wx.Image(get_main_dir()+"/picture.bmp",wx.BITMAP_TYPE_BMP).ConvertToBitmap()
```

Answer (score 1):

I do this using the approach outline [here](http://groups.google.com/group/PyInstaller/browse_thread/thread/e999838588e7fd99?pli=1).

Basically, this uses `from wx.tools import img2py` to convert an image to character string within a `.py` file.  One can then use `from wx.lib.embeddedimage import PyEmbeddedImage` at the top of this `.py` file to read in these character strings as bitmaps.

This way the images can be treated exactly as regular Python files.

For example, in the `images.py` file of the wxPython demo, the first few lines look like

```
from wx.lib.embeddedimage import PyEmbeddedImage

Mondrian = PyEmbeddedImage(
    "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACAAAAAgCAYAAABzenr0AAAABHNCSVQICAgIfAhkiAAAAHFJ"
    "REFUWIXt1jsKgDAQRdF7xY25cpcWC60kioI6Fm/ahHBCMh+BRmGMnAgEWnvPpzK8dvrFCCCA"
    "coD8og4c5Lr6WB3Q3l1TBwLYPuF3YS1gn1HphgEEEABcKERrGy0E3B0HFJg7C1N/f/kTBBBA"
    "+Vi+AMkgFEvBPD17AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC")
```

which is the little image that looks like a Mondrian painting.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have 2 different ways of running your program, with a different working folder for each.  Have you tried providing the complete absolute path to the picture.bmp file?

```
imag=wx.Image("C:/this/that/theother/picture.bmp",wx.BITMAP_TYPE_BMP).ConvertToBitmap()
```

Comment: hmm, does this work if i would run the program on another computer

Comment: Did you try it?  Did it work?  If it did, then it means that the problem is that you have a different working folder for the 2 ways of running your program.  The solution is to have you file in the working folder, or a subfolder.

Comment: You'd want to use a relative path though. Hard-coded paths almost always break.

Comment: Mike,  I am just trying to establish that the problem is with different working folders for the different ways of running the program.  Once the questioner understands the problem, the solution is straight forward and the questioner can solve it in various ways, depending on needs.